# How to avoid authentication from another PC working for a report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I deployed an SSRS report on my PC and am able to access my report through report manager.

When I copied that report URL and opened it on another PC over the network, it asked for credentials. I gave my system user name and password from the second PC and it's opened.

How to avoid credentials (my system Name and password) to open a report another pc ?

Answer (score 0):

The security credentials for the shared data source is probably set to "Windows integrated security". If you would like to change this, go to your Report Manager - Data Sources - Properties - General.
Here you can change to "Credentials are not required".

Comment: Have you tried to set it to "Use Windows Authentication" from the beginning or in the Report Manager?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I Set in the Report Manager.

Comment: Hi Daniel,Is their any problem